# Is there and Azure AD resource that can be requested in order to get JWT when passing username and password?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid, azure-active-directory

I have a multi tenant application and for a separate native application I am trying to implement a similar approach as described by [NativeClient-Headless-DotNet](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-Headless-DotNet). It works as intended when I have my multi tenant application and then I set up Native Client Application in Azure AD that I add permissions to mWeb App to. The request going out looks like this:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my tenant id}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
return-client-request-id: true
x-client-SKU: .NET
x-client-Ver: 2.14.0.0
x-client-CPU: x64
x-client-OS: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0    
x-client-last-response-time: 239
x-client-last-endpoint: user_realm
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Length: 173
Expect: 100-continue

resource={my web app uri id}&client_id={my native client app id}&grant_type=password&username={my username}&password={my password}&scope=openid
```

Works great for this prototype. I am trying to see if I could get away without the need for the Native client application to be registered in Azure AD. To do that, if we assume I could securely pass the username and password to my Web application, is there a way to request some resource from my Web application rather than my Native client application that would return response similar to the response from the above request? Something like:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my tenant id}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
return-client-request-id: true
x-client-SKU: .NET
x-client-Ver: 2.14.0.0
x-client-CPU: x64
x-client-OS: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0    
x-client-last-response-time: 239
x-client-last-endpoint: user_realm
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Length: 173
Expect: 100-continue

resource={some resource that requires authentication}&client_id={my web app id}&grant_type=password&username={my username}&password={my password}&scope=openid
```

Anything that is available in Azure AD? I could request Grap API token for example but that requires client_secret as it accesses the whole directory. I am looking for maybe something profile specific that will will work by passing username and password. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username/password flow is meant to be used only by native clients. AAD does not provide a mechanism for passing username/password to your won web site and use it form there - in fact it is strongly discouraged to have credentials circulate outside of the most direct path toward where validation takes place.